# Customize the background color and text color of a customTkinter window title bar

Tags: python, tkinter, background-color, titlebar, customtkinter

For my application, I'd like the native customkinter bar to change color and the text color too. I found a lot of weird libraries that did this, but it didn't work. For your information, because it's important to my problem, my operating system is Window10.

To help you with my problem, I'll give you the code for the initialization method of my class:

```
import customkinter

class FenetreLogin(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__();
        
        self.geometry("700x680");
        self.title("Exportation_Fanny v1");
        self.initial_width = 650;
        labelAuteur = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self,font=("",20,'underline'),text="Made By Lucas Desperrois");
        labelAuteur.pack(anchor="n",pady=10)
        self.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        self.fenetreConnexion = self.frameConnexion();
        self.browser1=None;
```

Comment: See [pywinstyles](https://github.com/Akascape/py-window-styles).  Note that it only works in Windows 10 or above.

Comment: I have seen this library but i not change the header_color in blue. It's only for window 11 no ?

Comment: The only way i found it's to choose the `appearance_mode` and you can choose between dark and light